# Query returning unfollowed users result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

First of all, this is going to be quite long and complex. So if you read through it, thanks.

So I have a follow and post system in PHP. So I could follow `Alex`, and I'd see Alex posts, along with my posts on the main wall. And if I unfollowed him, I'd not see his posts. This is what that query looks like

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE post_user IN ( SELECT follow_from 
                     FROM followers 
                     WHERE follow_to = :user 
                      OR follow_from = :user )
```

That gets the posts from people you're following. Wells that's what its supposed to do. Here's what posts looks like

```
+----+-----------+---------+------------------------+--------------+------------+
| id | post_user | post_ip | post_date              | post_content | post_likes |
+----+-----------+---------+------------------------+--------------+------------+
| 40 | idris     | ::1     | 07/09/2014 11:19:47 pm | I like food  | 0          | 
+----+-----------+---------+------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

Now say `Scott` which is another user, logs in. He goes to his wall, and he can see my post, even though he's not following me. That's the issue I'm having. Here's the `followers` table

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+
| id  | follow_from | follow_to |
+-----+-------------+-----------+
| 358 | idris       | scott     |
+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

I'd also expect to see his posts when I look at my wall. But I don't see anything (when there is a post in the DB). So essentially my question is, why does `Scott` see my posts on his wall, even through he's not following me.

I have tons of code, but I'll try to post on the important parts

How I run the query

```
$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * 
                      FROM posts 
                      WHERE post_user IN ( SELECT follow_from 
                                           FROM followers 
                                           WHERE follow_to = :user 
                                            OR follow_from = :user )");
$qry->bindValue(':user', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$qry->execute();
```

How I check if users are following

```
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] == true){
    $result1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * 
                              FROM followers 
                              WHERE follow_from = :user 
                              AND follow_to = :post_id");
    $result1->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $result1->bindParam(':post_id', $username);
    $result1->execute();
    $reprint = $result1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if($reprint > 1){
    $usr_flw = true;
}
else{
    $usr_flw = false;
}
```

And finally how I return posts

```
    $posts = array();
    while($row = $qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $posts[] =  array(
        'post_user' => $row['post_user'],
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'post_date' => $row['post_date'],
        'post_likes' => $row['post_likes'],
        'post_content' => $row['post_content']
    );
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain follow_to and follow_from ? Also, in your example, it seems Scott is the one in the DB so normally he should see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_user IN ( SELECT follow_to FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :user) OR post_user = :user
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming follow_from is the follower and follow_to is the followed user, your **subquery** should look something like this:

```
( SELECT follow_to FROM followers WHERE follow_from = :user )
```

This is going to return the users being followed by provided user.

Comment: Yeah but he needs the OR outside the IN to get his own posts too.

Comment: @Bob There was no explicit point about own posts for this particular query, but if that is the case, your answer is more complete :)